# How to migrate an odoo 11 app to odoo 12 successfully?

Tags: git, migration, odoo, porting, odoo-11

What are the steps ? In my case i need to migrate the hotel management app to odoo 12 git.

***[click here for the git repository of vertical hotel](https://github.com/athulvMkRz/vertical-hotel.git)***

Comment: https://github.com/OCA/maintainer-tools/wiki/Migration-to-version-12.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the steps to do it:

```
# clone the original repository
git clone <url>

# Create the second repository on your server

# once the repository is created add the second remote
git remote add odoo12 <new url>

# upload the code to your new repo
git push odoo12 --all
```

If you are using GitHub you can simply fork the project.....